# Efficient recall of a delta-based data log in Java

Tags: java, logging

My application has a number of objects in an internal list, and I need to be able to log them (e.g. once a second) and later recreate the state of the list at any time by querying the log file.

The current implementation logs the entire list every second, which is great for retrieval because I can simply load the log file, scan through it until I reach the desired time, and load the stored list.

However, the majority of my objects (~90%) rarely change, so it is wasteful in terms of disk space to continually log them at a set interval.

I am considering switching to a "delta" based log where only the changed objects are logged every second. Unfortunately this means it becomes hard to find the true state of the list at any one recorded time, without "playing back" the entire file to catch those objects that had not changed for a while before the desired recall time.

An alternative could be to store (every second) both the changed objects and the last-changed time for each unchanged object, so that a log reader would know where to look for them. I'm worried I'm reinventing the wheel here though — this must be a problem that has been encountered before.

Existing comparable techniques, I suppose, are those used in version control systems, but I'd like a native object-aware Java solution if possible — running `git commit` on a binary file once a second seems like it's abusing the intention of a VCS!

So, is there a standard way of solving this problem that I should be aware of? If not, any pitfalls that I might encounter when developing my own solution?

Comment: just zip the logfiles when you rotate them

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm not entirely clear what your suggestion is. Are you recommending logging all objects every second regardless of whether they have changed, then assuming good compression of the resulting files as they will have many binary-identical sections within them?

Comment: Yes.  Unless diskspace is a problem while logging, then don't worry, and let the compression algorithms handle shrinking duplicates when moving the logs into long term storage.